# Nikon D3500 damage while recording video

Tags: nikon, video

I read on a another photography site that the Nikon D3500 can overheat and suffer permanent damage while recording video. Does anyone know if there is any truth to this? It seems implausible that Nikon would sell a camera with this problem.

Comment: I read somewhere online that the Moon is made of green cheese...

Comment: Cute. So this is a site for jokers?

Comment: Well, you didn't exactly cite your own source in an acceptable way for a more formal environment...

Comment: And what is "acceptable" to you? Obviously no one has an answer, especially you. So you have nothing better to do than berate a post?

Comment: We have plenty of similar questions at Photo SE (which is where you originally posted this question) where the OP *does* cite their source so that those answering can look at the context of the claim. Please see, for example, [Do smaller apertures provide more depth of field past the diffraction limit, even if peak sharpness suffers?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11205/15871) or [What is the difference between "color" and "tones"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/72730/15871)